# Outlook 365 desktop email notification not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

Outlook 365 Desktop email notification is not working  after the windows update  20h2
i have done the following to address the issue but still the same if any one can help on this that will be grate.

1.ENABLED NOTIFICATIONS IN OUTLOOK APP
2.ENABLED OUTLOOK NOTIFICATIONS IN WINDOWS 10 SETTINGS
3.CHECKED NOTIFICATION RULES IN OUTLOOK APP
4.DISABLED FOCUS ASSIST
5.DISABLED BATTERY SAVER
6.MODIFIED THE REGISTRY ENTRY AS BELOW

1. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences
   DWORD: NewmailDesktopAlerts
   Value: 1
2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications
   DWORD: ToastEnabled
   Value: 1
3. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications
   DWORD: NoToastApplicationNotification
   Value: 0
4. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.Office.OUTLOOK.EXE.15
   DWORD:Enabled
   Value: 1
5. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.Office.OUTLOOK.EXE.16
   DWORD:Enabled
   Value: 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps if you turn them off and then enable them again.